# getting TypeError when running pylint on a module

Tags: python, qwidget, pylint

I wasn't expecting this what is happening that is causing this error:

```
 (develop)$ pylint   watcher.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 364, in getattr
    return [self.import_module(name, relative_only=True)]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 425, in import_module
    return MANAGER.ast_from_module_name(absmodname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 154, in ast_from_module_name
    return self.ast_from_module(module, modname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 220, in ast_from_module
    return AstroidBuilder(self).module_build(module, modname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 103, in module_build
    node = self.inspect_build(module, modname=modname, path=path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/raw_building.py", line 236, in inspect_build
    self.object_build(node, module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/raw_building.py", line 279, in object_build
    class_node = object_build_class(node, member, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astroid/raw_building.py", line 145, in object_build_class
    basenames = [base.__name__ for base in member.__bases__]
TypeError: C++ type 'QWidget*' is not supported as  type
```

Comment: Does the code work normally?

Comment: Yes. It works as I am already using this tool I've made.

Comment: you should ensure this occurs with the latest and greatest pylint/astroid and if so report the pb on pylint's tracker (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues)